# Speeding up Project Euler 43 - sub-string divisibility

Tags: python, optimization, performance, strings, programming-challenge

> The number, 1406357289, is a 0 to 9 pandigital number because it is
>   made up of each of the digits 0 to 9 in some order, but it also has a
>   rather interesting sub-string divisibility property.
>
> Let *d<sub>1</sub>* be the 1<sup>st</sup> digit, *d<sub>2</sub>* be the 2<sup>nd</sup> digit, and so on. In this way,
>   we note the following:
>
> - *d<sub>2</sub>d<sub>3</sub>d<sub>4</sub>*=406 is divisible by 2
> - *d<sub>3</sub>d<sub>4</sub>d<sub>5</sub>*=063 is divisible by 3
> - *d<sub>4</sub>d<sub>5</sub>d<sub>6</sub>*=635 is divisible by 5
> - *d<sub>5</sub>d<sub>6</sub>d<sub>7</sub>*=357 is divisible by 7
> - *d<sub>6</sub>d<sub>7</sub>d<sub>8</sub>*=572 is divisible by 11
> - *d<sub>7</sub>d<sub>8</sub>d<sub>9</sub>*=728 is divisible by 13
> - *d<sub>8</sub>d<sub>9</sub>d<sub>10</sub>*=289 is divisible by 17
>
> Find the sum of all 0 to 9 pandigital numbers with this property.

[Project Euler 43](http://projecteuler.net/problem=43)

```
from itertools import permutations
from primes import primes_upto
from collections import Counter
from timeit import default_timer as timer

start = timer()
def follows_property(n):
    divisors = primes_upto(17)
    for k in range(7):
        if int(n[k:(k+3)]) % divisors[k] != 0:
            return False
    return True

ans = 0
digits = Counter(range(10))

start = timer()

for combo in permutations(range(10), 9):
    num = ''.join([str(x) for x in list(combo)])
    if follows_property(num):
        missing = int(list((digits - Counter(sorted([int(k) for k in str(num)]))).elements())[0])
        num = int(num)
        ans += int("%d%d" % (missing, num))


elapsed_time = (timer() - start) * 1000 # s --> ms

print "Found %d in %r ms." % (ans, elapsed_time)
```

Comment: Can the first digit in a number be `0`, i.e., is every nine-digit number consisting of the digits `1` through `9` a base-10 pandigital number because you can stick `0` on the front?

Comment: I believe it can't start with a 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make a few quick improvements without altering the algorithm significantly:

- Remove one of the redundant calls to `timer()`.
- Store the list of primes instead of calculating it for every call to `follows_property`.
- Convert the digits to strings in the list passed to `permutations` so you can simplify the calculation of `num`.
- Run through all permutations instead of 9-tuples and remove the `Counter` and `missing` parts.

These are minor changes, but they clean up the code a bit. I also renamed `ans` to `sum` to clarify what it holds. They also cut the running time by more than half.

```
from itertools import permutations
from primes import primes_upto
from collections import Counter
from timeit import default_timer as timer

divisors = primes_upto(17)

def follows_property(n):
    for k in range(7):
        if int(n[k+1:(k+4)]) % divisors[k] != 0:
            return False
    return True

sum = 0
start = timer()

for combo in permutations([str(x) for x in range(10)]):
    num = ''.join(combo)
    if follows_property(num):
        sum += int(num)

elapsed_time = (timer() - start) * 1000 # s --> ms

print("Found %d in %r ms." % (sum, elapsed_time))
```

Comment: I just posted another answer to this question @DavidHarkness. I originally wanted to just post the idea as a comment on your answer because I liked your answer. However, my ideas would have been too jumbled in a comment. So please feel free to use any code you see fit from my answer to augment yours. +1

Answer (score 4):

Instead of brute-forcing 10! permutations, I'd recommend going other way around: construct the necessary ones.

You know already that the last 3 digits must form a multiple of 17 - there's just 50 or so such numbers, provided that all 3 digits shall be different. Then prepend each of them with one of remaining 7 digits (350 things to try) eliminating those which do not yield a multiple of 13. Proceed with one more digit, etc.

I hope you see the point.

Answer (score 0):

[@DavidHarkness](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/1635/david-harkness) detailed nicely what needs to be done. However, I would add a couple more checks to ensure that any unnecessary permutations aren't processed:

```
for combo in permutations([str(x) for x in range(10)]):
    num = ''.join(combo)

    # This ensures that the second triple of numbers is even and the 
    # fourth triplet is divisible by 5.
    if int(num[3]) % 2 == 0 and num[5] in ['0', '5']:
        if follows_property(num):
            found += 1
            sum += int(num)
```

Comment: Are those digit-tests backwards? Are you sure there are nine numbers that satisfy the condition?

Comment: You were right, they were backwards. Thanks for the catch. And for the numbers, it must be true for the problem to be solvable. The only way a number would fit is if its 2nd triplet is divisible by 2 (i.e. must end in an even number) and if the 4th triple is divisible by 5 (i.e. must end in a 0 or a 5)

Comment: My second question was referring to "If we have found all 9 numbers, stop."

Comment: Oops. I misread the problem statement. I thought they said that there were only 9 possible permutations. Will fix accordingly.